# Are Plesk or cPanel helpful for bringing up new VPS servers?

Tags: webserver, vps, configuration, control-panel

I'm a programmer, and I like to create some website by my own (php, or asp.net).

Until today, have manually configured the VPS servers that I've bought. (So for instance for an Ubuntu VPS, I install and manually configure users, lamp, ssl, firewall, etc) with sometime a lot of pain using command line and bash.

Are Plesk and /or  cPanel  (or any other tool in that category) a smarter way to do that? So Can I forget how to configure and manage an empty (newly installed) VPS and just let Plesk or cPanel doing the job?

For job I intend: install and configure LAMP stack, new hosted websites and linked users, ssl, firewall, backup?

Comment: In addition to the answer you've received below, you may like a GUI rather than having to deal with things in the terminal. VestaCP is an example of such software. You may also want to look into hosting providers who provide "1-click-apps" or "1-click-deployments", where they will use an image to create a new VPS for you that already has things configured a certain way, or you could use a snapshot of one VPS to create other VPSes with the same configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plesk and cPanel are for managing shared hosting.  You would install one of them if you had several people hosting websites on the same machine or VPS.   I would not recommend installing them if only one person or company is going to put websites on that machine.   Far from making your life easier, they will increase the amount of configuration that you need to do.

I would instead focus on using a configuration automation tool such as [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/).   Ansible has built in modules for most tasks to  get a LAMP server up and running:

- [apt module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html) for installing packages
- [user module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html) for managing user accounts
- [apache2 module module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/apache2_module_module.html) for enabling or disabling Apache modules
- and many others

If you need to change something on your server, you can run Ansible again, and it will only update the parts that need to change.   If it doesn't have a built in task, it is easy to create a custom task using your shell scripts.   Once you configure Ansible to bring up a server the way you want it, bringing up a second server is trivial.